# Printer not actually printing

Tags: printing

i am trying to print, computer sends signal,printer lights up HP. Does not actually print paper,but computer says job completed.

Comment: We could use a bit more information... at least the make and model of the printer and whether or not you've installed proprietary drivers and what version of Ubuntu etc.

Comment: Open CUPS, select Printers, select your printer, from the Maintenance dropdown list choose Resume Printer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the printer (remove then add printer), this helps in most cases.

Comment: please provide details how to remove and add printer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was called in to resolve this problem in the Xray department of a hospital (which I won't name). Root cause: No paper in the printer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a HP Printer (1018). I faced similar problems before. Even if my printer was automatically detected by the HP drivers, the printer never responded.

By reinstalling the HP drivers this issue gets easily solved. 
We can do this on a terminal.

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```